# Cesium WebGL Camera Rotate, How to Stop the Rotation

Tags: javascript, rotation, cesiumjs

OK, first time using Cesium. I have a simple, non-advanced question that I posted a couple times on their forms but no one is responding. So I thought I'd try here.

All I need to do is figure out how to stop an event before invoking another. Here's an example of what's happening. The globe spins on user-connect, but I need it to stop if they then click on "fly me home", etc.

Code below.

So the arg in spinGlobe is the spinRate. If I pass in 0.0 on the inital connect, it won't rotate. Perfect. So I though that if a click event ( user clicks fly me home ) then invoked spinGlobe(0.0) that the globe would stop rotating. But it doesn't. Can I not dynamically change the spinRate? Or am I going about this all wrong?

```
spinGlobe( 0.5 )

 function spinGlobe( dynamicRate )
 var previousTime = Date.now();

 viewer.clock.onTick.addEventListener(function( clock ) {
 var spinRate = dynamicRate;
 var currentTime = Date.now();
 var delta = ( currentTime - previousTime ) / 1000;
 previousTime = currentTime;
 viewer.scene.camera.rotate(Cesium.Cartesian3.UNIT_Z, -spinRate * delta);
 });
 }
```

Comment: Just an FYI I finally got it working. The guys over Cesium responded. Turned out i just need to use plain old JS event listeners. For whatever reason I was going down a rabbit's hole in the Cesium event listener docs! So all good!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: @ScottJason: Could you share the solution. I would like to know more about it

Answer (score 0):

```
spinGlobe( dynamicRate ){
    var previousTime = Date.now();

    this.viewer.scene.postRender.addEventListener(function (scene, time){
        var spinRate = dynamicRate;
        var currentTime = Date.now();
        var delta = ( currentTime - previousTime ) / 1000;
        previousTime = currentTime;
        this.viewer.scene.camera.rotate(Cesium.Cartesian3.UNIT_Z, -spinRate * delta);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how to stop the rotation because i was trying to stop it by `spinGlobe(0)` but this is not working